# How to disabled a combobox according to the selection in another combobox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have this block of code that is giving me results for a combo box,  I would like it to ignore the combo box and disable it when the value "SDO/OD" is selected in the one above under the combo box for ROLE aka fcbRole.  The following enables the box from the first part, but the second part does not fire off.  And it gives me a warning: "This field is required"...Have you seen something like this before?

I have been tinkering with:

```
            fcbRole.addSelectionChangedListener(new SelectionChangedListener<ModelData>()
    {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<ModelData> se) 
        {   
             if ("SDO/OD".equals(this.toString()))
                             {
                                 fcbOfficeRegion.enable();
                             } else 
                             {
                                 fcbOfficeRegion.disable();
                             }
        }       

    });
```

Comment: As a side note, don't compare strings using `==`. Use `.equals`.

Comment: You're aware of the default implementation of `toString()`, aren't you? I bet you always run into the `!= "SDO/OD"` case, right? That would have two reasons: 1. `!=` and `==` compare the memory addresses, i.e. if the objects are the same, not if they have the same value. 2. `toString()` will by default return the class name and some hash, and you call `toString()` on the `SelectionChangedListener` you create.

Comment: It's a little redundant anyway; why do the second comparison (once you stop using `==`)? If it's equal, it's equal; there's only one other option.

Comment: What gives you the "This field is required" waring? Are you talking about an Exception? Can you post the error text?

Comment: @Dave maybe he has a third option :)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `==` and `!=` to compare `Strings`, instead use:

```
if("SDO/OD".equals(this.getStringName()) // or make sure you override toString()
     // enable
else 
     // disable
```

Answer (score 1):

For String value equality, use `equals()` method and not operators. Operators does reference equality check.

So, change your code to:

```
        if ("SDO/OD".equals(this.toString()))
        {
            fcbOfficeRegion.enable();
        } else 
        {
            fcbOfficeRegion.disable();
        }
```

Comment: It still gives me the red outline around the combo box with the warning: "This field is required"..  Basically, I wanted to pass the SDO/OD when chosen in the fcbRole combo box, then enable() fcbOfficeRegion.  But, when you have something else in fcbRole ignore/disable fcbOfficeRegion.